# ArcMap trial 2022

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, installation

I am searching for trial account for ArcMap desktop version.
Is ArcMap trial for Desktop is deprecated or there is a way to try ArcMap desktop version?

Comment: A trial is for a new software product.  Wouldn't using Pro be more appropriate at this point?

Comment: There is no such thing as ArcMap Trial, you can get a trial for ArcGIS Online, using which you can access ArcGIS Pro, but for ArcMap, it's a No-No.

Answer (score 1):

[As of 2020 ArcMap is in Continued Support status](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-desktop/announcements/arcmap-continued-support/#:%7E:text=ArcGIS%2010.8.,the%20ArcGIS%20releases%20in%202021.), with new versions no longer being released. [The full product support lifecycle can be found here](https://support.esri.com/en/Products/Desktop/arcgis-desktop/arcmap/10-8-1#product-support). Therefore they no longer have trial versions available.

If you are looking for a free trial of the current Esri desktop GIS software, take a look at the [21 day free trial for ArcGIS Pro](https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/arcgis-pro/trial).